# How do I output comparison for certain columns only using SAS?

Tags: sas

I am trying to compare two Excel worksheets (two different workbooks). 
1) I have imported both files - fine
2) I have written some code in SAS and it brings out the correct output

Now, I would like for it to only output comparison for those column headings which have the word 'biggest' in it.

Here is the code:

```
PROC COMPARE
BASE=WORK.DATA_201605 
COMPARE=WORK.DATA_201606 
out=dif
outbase
outcomp
outnoequal
listall
OUTDIF 
METHOD=PERCENT 
CRITERION=10.00 maxprint=(1000);
ID Mainid;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dictionary.columns` SQL view to determine the columns :

```
proc sql ;
  select distinct name into :VARLIST separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = 'DIF'
    and upcase(name) like '%BIGGEST%' ;
quit ;

proc print data=dif ;
  var &VARLIST ;
run ;
```

Comment: To be more explicit, this would end after the `PROC SQL` to filter/select variables in your code: `PROC COMPARE BASE=WORK.DATA_201605(keep=&VARLIST.) COMPARE=WORK.DATA_201606(keep=&varlist.)...`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the VAR statement? Along with colon to shortcut your prefix. 
Something like:

```
Var biggest: ;
```

Comment: I have many columns with the word biggest in them. So I only need comparisons done for columns that have the word 'biggest' in them. How would I edit the code? Sorry I am fairly new with SAS.

Comment: The colon tells SAS to look at all columns that start with the prefix biggest. Add this line to you proc compare before the Run statement.

Comment: I read it as starts with biggest. If biggest can be anywhere in the name this won't work.